# Ace editor + Angular 2 => protractor cannot synchronize

Tags: angular, protractor, ace-editor, angular-cli

I'm developing an app using Angular 2 (2.0.0 release), angular-cli (1.0.0-beta.14).

I've integrated Ace editor using an Angular 2 directive, following https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor

As soon as the Ace editor is instantiated, protractor cannot synchronize anymore:

```
✗ should display app name
  - Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, app-root .navbar a.active)
```

The Ace editor is instantiated using:

```
import { EventEmitter, Output, ElementRef, Input, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import 'brace';
import 'brace/theme/chrome';
import 'brace/mode/html';

declare var ace: any;

@Directive({
   selector: '[aceEditor]'
})
export class AceEditorDirective {
  editor: any;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
    let el = elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.editor = ace['edit'](el); // Comment this line and Protractor works again
  }
}
```

Any hint what's the issue ?

Comment: Looks like when Ace Editor is instantiated, Angular cannot tell anymore that it is ready: `window.getAngularTestability($('app-root')).whenStable(function(){console.log('stable')})` does not print anything anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally found the issue.
It looks like Angular is lost tracking changes in the Ace Editor, hence thinks there are always ongoing changes. So

```
window.getAngularTestability($('app-root'))
    .whenStable(funct‌​ion(){
        console.log('s‌​table')
    })
```

Does not return anymore when Ace Editor is instantiated.

Easy solution: instantiate the Ace Editor out of the zone:

```
constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, zone: NgZone) {
  let el = elementRef.nativeElement;
  zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    this.editor = ace['edit'](el);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue as above and instead of running the ace editor outside of Angular, I rather made multiple tests in protractor which would continue from where the previous test left off. Ace Editor would cause the browser not to finish synchronizing and hence my protractor test would time out.

You could have the tests as follows:

```
it('Runs Tests for components with ace edit')
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  testAngularElements();

it('Runs the rest of the test in which the ace edit is not present')
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
  remainingTests();
```

Unfortunately I could not find an alternative approach yet.